# Flutter Google Sign In idToken expired

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin

I am using google_sign_in for auth in my flutter application.

I followed steps documented here to get started:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart

I get idToken as recommended to perform auth on the server side.

This is the code snippet I use to get idToken

```dart
_googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen(
            (GoogleSignInAccount account) {
      setState(() {
        developer.log("************Changing account");
        _currentUser = account;
        account.authentication.then((key){
          developer.log("########### Changing token");
          _userToken=key.idToken;
        });

      });
    });
```

When I send idToken (_userToken in above example) it works fine for sometime, and later I see the following error message on the server side:

Token expired, 1593370077 < 1593384191

IT looks like token has an expiration time and expires after a while.

I tried moving above code snippet from initState() to build(). Here my assumption if I call it everytime when I am building the widget I should get a new token. THAT DIDN'T WORK

Reason I thought it might work was because when I "Run .dart" (not hot reload) it works. This made me assume moving it to build might work . It didn't work

My question: What is the programmatic way to refresh token, or get a new token in flutter using google_sign_in.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

The idToken expires every 30 minutes.
To refresh the token you can either user the [API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) or do a silent login like this:

```dart
Future<String> refreshToken() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
        await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );
    await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

    return googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken; //new token
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Will try that

Is GoogleAuthProvider part of google_sign_in flutter package or is it part of other flutter package that I should install

Comment: its part of `firebase_auth` package

Comment: Do you know why it works when I force refresh or "Run .dart" application on emulator, but not on hot reloads.

Either way I will install firebase_auth and will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Finally got a chance to try this solution but I am still running into the same issue.

By calling refreshToken() I see the following error:


 Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL, The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ ID Token issued at 1594524874 is stale to sign-in. ], null)

Comment: @JideGuru, how do you determine if a token is expired?  If a user uses my app for more than 30 minutes, the token expires while they are using the app and hence it results in a bad user experience. What's the workaround this apart from autologout? Any ideas?